# Active records complex relationship query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following scenario:

```
User->HABTM->businesses

Suppliers->HABTM->businesses

Suppliers->HAS_MANY->Payments
```

I am having real trouble working out how to get all the payments for a user through the HABTM relationships that describe the business->supplier and User->business relationship.

I am after all payments that belong to the user through the supplier business relationship.

I can do this with SQL very easily but am having trouble doing it the rails way.

It's similar to a post on getting all the comments that belong to a user via a post model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Is it even possible?

I am doing this at the moment:

```
has_many :payments,:finder_sql => Proc.new {
  %Q{
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM payments 
    INNER JOIN businesses_users ON businesses_users.user_id
    INNER JOIN businesses_suppliers ON businesses_suppliers.business_id        
    WHERE payments.supplier_id = businesses_suppliers.supplier_id AND businesses_users.user_id = #{id}
    ORDER BY payments.created_at
  }}
```

This lets me do user.payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda pressed for time, but wanted to chime in. First, your models seem to suggest that there might be an IS A relationship between User and Supplier, in which case you could employ polymorphic associations. If that's not the case, I'd look into the includes option within the activerecord query interface. In that manner, you can basically force AR to eager load the relationships down the chain. An example might look like:

all_users_and_their_pmts = User.includes(:businesses => {:suppliers => :payments })

An alternative, but highly inefficient, way to do this would be:

user_record.businesses.map {|b| b.suppliers.map {|s| s.payments}}.flatten

which would give you an array of payments. Using raw sql like you have above will be far more efficient than this, since activerecord can't chain the calls within map{}. I think :include would be a more idiomatic way for you to go, but your solution isn't horrible.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will give the include options, just been experimenting with it and it seems to be working, just a bit worried about the efficiency once the number of Users, Businesses, Suppliers and Payments starts to grow. Mind you, no less efficient that doing inner joins....

Comment: Ok - I came up with **Payment.paginate(:page=>page, :per_page=>10).all(:include=>[:supplier => {:businesses => :users}], :conditions=>"users.id = #{self.id}")** which solved it. Thanks for the pointer Alex.